# Inappbrowser error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I´m trying to open a Webview into my Ionic 2 application but I have the next issue when I tried to open : [image]

I´m using the next code in my app.controller:

```
$scope.openInAppBrowser = function()
         {
       window.open('https://appr.tc/','_blank','location=no','toolbar=yes');
        };
```

Do you know how can I solve this problem?.
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove and add inAppBrowser plugin again.